Using AzureBlobFileSystem to Access Azure Blob Storage Fails with Import Error
I'm trying to use AzureBlobFileSystem from the adlfs library to access Azure Blob Storage as a file system in Python. I’m encountering an import error and would appreciate any help.
I’ve installed azure-storage-blob and adlfs:
pip install azure-storage-blob adlfs

My code:
import fsspec
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem
abfs = AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name=account_name,account_key="")

When I run this code, I get the following error:
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem
ImportError: cannot import name 'AzureBlobFileSystem' from partially initialized module 'adlfs' (most likely due to a circular import)
What I've Tried:

Verified that my account name and key are correct.
Ensured that azure-storage-blob and adlfs are both installed and up-to-date.
Checked my network connection and confirmed I have access to the
storage account.

Environment detail  :
Editor - VS code on Mac os
python - 3.13.0
adlfs - 2024.7.0
azure-storage-blob - 12.23.1
I am using all the latest version for azure libraries.
Has anyone encountered this before or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Thank you for your help!

Can you restart the vs code and try it? In my environment, it is working successfully same azure-storage-blob =12.23.1  and adlfs =2024.7.0 and sample output using AzureBlobFileSystem.

which python version your using ? its giving error with - python - 3.13.0

I'm using Python 3.11.9 will check with your version.

Yeah, its working can you check in your environment and also check the pip environment same and uninstall older versions.

@Venkatesan Thank you for looking into this - I have checked in my Conda env and there is only one version for both the packages : % conda list | grep adlfs
adlfs       2024.7.0     pypi_0    pypi
% conda list | grep azure-storage-blob
azure-storage-blob   12.23.1   pypi_0    pypi

The issue was due to naming my Python file with an existing Python keyword (e.g., azure.py).
Solution:
I renamed the file to something unique, avoiding reserved keywords and built-in module names. For example, instead of class.py, I renamed it to my_class.py, which resolved the error.
Thanks to everyone who tried to look into this !!
